# Can't select text because of AJAX

Tags: ajax, chat, selection

I have an AJAX chat. AJAX reloads session every 750ms so it deselect text which I selected in chat. How can I solve it?

My code:

```
 document.getElementById('content-frame').onload = msg_loading();
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#content-frame').load('<? echo('init/conversation.php?uid='.$id.'&cid='.$u['id']); ?>');
        }, 750);
    });
```

Comment: You can look into the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange). What have you tried? Ideally, if you've built the chat yourself, you shouldn't be doing a simple refresh... whatever script you're using should be able to dynamically update any mutated messages or append new messages...

Comment: can  you post some code? It's hard to get the context of the problem you are having with that description.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock I edited the code. Check it please.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would be reloading the data via ajax on the page that contains the chat. Like so:

[image]

Right now you have your chat box reloading from the "Main page" which I think is the problematic part. I would use ajax to call a REST API instead. This will solve your problem with the page reloading and deselecting the text because the page is not reloading, the data is being updated via ajax.

```
   setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
           url: '/conversation-rest-api.php?uid=' + uid
      })
      .done(function(data){
           // Use templating tool to generate html from `data`
           // var content = getContentFromData(data);
           $('#content-output').html(content);
      });
   }, 750);
```

Comment: but content-frame isn't iframe :(

Comment: If you aren't using iframe you can just skip the "conversation" page. The main thing here is I think you should be using a REST API and generating the html in the javascript instead of your php page. You can use something like Mustache for templating.

Comment: Can you please make new answer and write there example code of that REST API?

Comment: A REST API returns a JSON payload instead of an HTML payload, I'm sure you can do the research yourself on this.